# Keyboard shortcut for start dictation from PC keyboard

Tags: keyboard, voice-dictation

When my laptop is closed at home and I am using a PC keyboard, I cannot access Start Dictation with "fn fn" because there's no fn key on my keyboard. How can I get a keyboard shortcut for this?

I tried setting up Karabiner but was unsuccessful. Instructions appreciated. Could have shift-lock or F9 for my fn key.

Or is there a way to change the keyboard shortcut for this to something else?

I'm on El Capitan (10.11.3). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to easily change the shortcut for Dictation from the [`Dictation` preference pane in `System Preferences`](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT202584).

> **Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Dictation & Speech. Turn on Dictation, then choose from these Dictation options:**
>
> Choose the keyboard shortcut you will use to signal that you're ready to start dictating.
>
> [image: https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/osx/el-capitan-system-preferences-dictation-speech-animation.gif]

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know there were dictation preferences. Thanks :)